# About the image of an $S^1$-bundle in a simply connected manifold

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles

Let $\pi : E \to M$ be a smooth fibre bundle with fibre $S^1$. Let $N$ be a simply connected manifold. Let $f: E \to N$ be any continuous map. Is $f$ homotopic to $g \circ \pi$ for some continuous $g : M \to N$?

The idea is that one might be able to shrink each $S^1$ fibre in the image of $f$ to a point, since $N$ is simply connected, and obtain the image of a map $g: M \to N$. Thus, the image of $f$ would potentially retract onto that of $g$ inside $N$. Would this work? I know this isn't rigorous at all, just a heuristic, but I'm struggling to come up with an actual proof for this.

Comment: Have you considered looking for a counterexample?

Comment: @Kajelad I tried to play with easy examples such as tori and the Hopf fibration embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$, but they seem to work.

Comment: Try something simpler. E.g., the identity $S^1\to S^1$ does not factor through a singleton, even modulo homotopy.

Comment: @Kajelad Right I was just about to write that the identity $S^3 \to S^3$ probably doesn't work, since it is not nullhomotopic, yet any map $S^2 \to S^3$ is. Yours is simpler though, thanks!

Comment: @Kajelad Ah but $S^1$ is not simply connected, so your example doesn't quite work. Nevertheless, the $S^3$ one seems to work, and now I'm curious whether if one allows the dimension of $N$ to be sufficiently large, my idea holds true?

Comment: I read it as $M$, not $N$ being simply connected. Still, your Hopf version works. I don't think dimensional bounds will work, since a similar argument works for the generalized Hopf bundle $S^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{CP}(n)$.

Comment: @Kajelad By that I meant for $N$ to be sufficiently large but with the dimension of $M$ (and hence $E$) fixed. So $S^3 \to N$ for example.

Comment: I see. Still, the essential problem is that $\pi$ can map some homotopy invaiants non-injectively which won't generally go away in higher dimension.

Comment: The dimension condition is not crucial, take $M \to N \times \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n$ large, up to homotopy this is the same as maps $M \to N$. So for your counterexample, take $S^3 \to S^3 \times \mathbb{R}^n$ mapping $x \mapsto (x, 0)$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the Hopf fibration $\pi:S^3\to S^2$ gives a counterexample with the identity map $S^3\to S^3$.  More generally, any $S^1$-bundle $\pi:E\to M$ where $E$ is a simply connected closed manifold will give a counterexample with the identity map $E\to E$ (which cannot factor up to homotopy through any manifold of lower dimension since $E$ is closed).  To explore how you can get such examples, note that an $S^1$-bundle $E\to M$ gives an exact sequence of homotopy groups $$0\to\pi_2(E)\to \pi_2(M)\to\pi_1(S^1)\to\pi_1(E)\to\pi_1(M)\to 0$$ and so $\pi_1(E)$ will be trivial as long as $\pi_1(M)$ is trivial and the map $\pi_2(M)\to\pi_1(S^1)$ is surjective.  In the case of a principal $S^1$-bundle (i.e. one whose structure group is $S^1\cong U(1)$), the map $\pi_2(M)\to\pi_1(S^1)$ can be identified with the map $\pi_2(M)\to \pi_2(BU(1))$ induced by the map $M\to BU(1)$ classifying the bundle.  Moreover, since $BU(1)$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, every homomorphism $\pi_2(M)\to\mathbb{Z}$ is induced by a map $M\to BU(1)$ if $M$ is simply connected.  The upshot of all of this is that if $M$ is any simply connected closed manifold with a surjective homomorphism $\pi_2(M)\to \mathbb{Z}$, this induces a map $M\to BU(1)$ which classifies an $S^1$-bundle $\pi:E\to M$ such that $E$ is simply connected and so the identity map $E\to E$ is a counterexample to your question.